# Android Airbnb like Tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, android-tabhost, android-actionbaractivity

I am trying to figure out how airbnb has implemented its Tab Bar, it either seems they have hidden their actionbar and everything has been shifted onto a tab bar but then the right most user icon opens the navigation drawer which should be ideally on actionbar, Or everything is on action bar itself but then how can those 3 tabs/icons on left be implemented on actionbar. (Kindly refer attached image)

[image]

Can somebody put some light on how this can be implemented. How to go about it? Also are those 3 icons fragments or separate activities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, is a library which makes your life simpler to implement TabBarView for actionbar tabs.

https://github.com/Mirkoddd/TabBarView

This should give you insight about how to use it for your app.

Comment: Great ! just what i needed. Any clue how will side navigation drawer be incorporated using this library ?

Comment: Yes, you can !! Use Drawer layout and NavigationView classes in your MainActivity. You need to use android design library.

Comment: I know how to use Navigation Drawer Layout, the issue is we dont have original actionbar here which usually contains the drawer opening button(home button) on top left. How will we incorporate that here ? Thanks.